# react setState refreshes boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

i'm trying to update the state using object which consists of something like that:

```
Object {check1: false, check2: true, check3: false}
```

but when i'm adding it with a setState

```
this.setState({check : tmpObj});
```

all the values became "false" in the state, while tmpObj itself keeps the same.

[here](https://pastebin.com/KegTdUHz) is a code example. I'm loading the list of criterias presented as checkboxes, and this function is created for onChange event.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Better if you share your complete component code.

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/KegTdUHz) i'm loading the list of criterias presented as checkboxes

Comment: setState replaces the entire object and triggers rendering. The new object you pass in to setState doesn't have check1, check2 and check3 properties.

Comment: if i will change "checkState" inside setSate for anything else, it will add 3 items "check1", "check2" and "check3" with "false" values, so it difinitely have this properties.

Comment: but you was write at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem myself, be careful with updating values trough render() function